# Adding border forces column to next line when using Responsive Grid System?

Tags: css

I am trying to use the Responsive Grid System CSS code (http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) to build my first website. I am having a slight issue when adding borders to the columns, as doing so forces the last column to the next line. I am not sure how to approach fixing this issue.

So for example, this would force the last column to the next line:

```
    .span_4_of_12 {
          border: 1px solid black;
     }
```

I would like to add borders to the column without forcing to the next line. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;`.  This rule will make the border part of the calculation of the element's width.

[Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizin)